# Inheritance/ Casting Problem (BufferedImages

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, bufferedimage

Ok so this is the KernelHandler Class

getWidth() is a method of the BufferedImage Class

`public class KernelHandler extends ImageHandler`

I'm getting a cannot find method getWidth()

I know it has something to do with inheritance, but I need help, please

//Heres the contructor

`public KernelHandler(String nameOfFile)`
`{`

`super(nameOfFile);`

```
}
```

`// here's the super constructor`

`public ImageHandler(String  nameOfFile){`

```
 URL imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(nameOfFile);
try
{
 myImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    System.out.println( "image missing" );
}
```

// Here's the method were trying to use

`public static int numOfRedBoxes(String nameOfImg)`

```
{
    KernelHandler myHand = new KernelHandler(nameOfImg);
    for(int i = 0; i < myHand.getWidth(); i++)

        for(int j = 0; j < myHand.getHeight(); j++){
            if(img.getRGB(i, j) == red){
                numOfRedBoxes++;
           }   
        }
   }
  return numOfRedBoxes;
```

}